# Propel, Filter Column that is blank/empty

Tags: php, propel

Im trying to select rows from a table in propel 1.6 where a particular column is blank.

so for example if my query looks like this:

```
$result = TableQuery::create()
         ->filterByContainer("")
         ->find();
```

I know 100% there are rows where the 'container' column is blank but if I print_r($result) the Propel Collection object has no results.  If I change the query to filter the container column with a particular value e.g 'test' it works fine.

Im sure Im missing something really simple but a google around hasnt give me the answer, neither has the Propel documentation and my attempts at guessing has just caused php fatal errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This may have been a problem on an earlier version. But with 1.7.1 the way you've got it in the question works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha in a twist of luck I just tried something out of the blue and it worked. All I had to do was remove the "" like this:

```
$result = TableQuery::create()
         ->filterByContainer()
         ->find();
```

my results are now fine =)